# can zero page be mapped or address zero be written to?

Tags: c, pointers

I was quite surprised to read that Zero Page can be mapped under x86 and certain architectures.  At least the case on Solaris and he had an example of exploit by mapping the zero page. which is essentially memset the address zero.

In my understanding the Address 0 and around was setup specially to protect from being accessed, at least on windows. but I am not so sure of that, so I wrote some code myself [here](http://ideone.com/jyVZGM)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    void* mem = (void*)-1;
    memset( mem, 0x00, 4*1024 );

    return 0;
}
```

As expected, at least on ideone, it crashes. is there really the case of mapping zero page ?

Answer (score 3):

On many operating systems you can explicitly tell the operating system where to map something including page 0. You can't expect something to be mapped there, but you can wrestle the operating system into mapping something there. On unix-like systems it could be done with `mmap(0, ..., MAP_FIXED ...)`.

This has been shown to be a bad idea to allow on systems where the kernel and userland share the same address space because it allows a NULL dereference that would normally just crash the kernel to escalate into a much more serious attack, potentially even allowing an attacker to run code in kernel mode.

After this class of attacks has been discovered many systems explicitly prevent mapping things to page 0 (or rather to a number of pages in the lowest virtual space to prevent larger offsets into buffers with NULL pointers), but there are actually buggy applications out there that require this ability so some operating systems still allow it and have elaborate schemes to prevent this from being exploitable.

Comment: so windows and other OS don't allow it now ?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the details. I've seen it fixed brutally (as in: never allow) in two different operating systems and heard rumors about others doing strange hacks. But I don't have more details than that. You'd have to research your particular operating system to figure out what it does and doesn't allow.

Answer (score 1):

The mapping of the page including the address 0 depends on the operating system. Imaging a micro-controller design that probably doesn't have protection at all.